# Ping unlocks ipsec vpn

Tags: vpn, ipsec, ping, pfsense

I have a ipsec vpn with a foreign company, this connects my network with their network and they have a different ip subnet. Ipsec is made by a pfsense gateway/firewall.

I'm sure it is well configured, all ipsec params are set and the tunnel looks established.

However foreign colegues cannot connect to my machines, but I have a clue!
If I run a ping from my pfsense ipsec interface to foreign ip address magically it starts working and they can connect!!

If they need to connect again after few hours I have to ping them again and so on.... And it works only with ping from ipsec interface.

For me is strange to solve a network problem with a ping. What can be the cause? Where should I focus my search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this behavior before where the VPN tunnel will only stay up when a ping is done from one end of the VPN tunnel to the other. There could be a few reasons for this. First I would check the SA lifetime on both ends of the tunnel. If there is a mismatch in either seconds or bytes for the lifetime then the VPN appliance (in your case the pfsense gateway/fiewall) with the higher SA lifetime will be able to start the VPN tunnel but it would not work the other way meaning if they tried pining you and they had a lower SA lifetime it would not be able to negotiate up to a higher SA lifetime and no VPN tunnel would start for phase 1 or phase 2. Second I would also check firewall settings on both ends as I have seen very odd firewall configurations in the past that have also caused similar behavior, but without being able to see your topology I am not sure if that is your problem.

Comment: Thank you I will check it. Don't you think it could be a routing problem?

Comment: Almost certainly not a routing problem.  Otherwise the ping wouldn't work.  It's a problem with the tunnel as @brianhalbach suggests.

Comment: Maybe this param can be a solution... : https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/What_should_I_ping_for_IPsec_Keep_Alive